# Расположение элементов в GridBarLayout

Tags: java, swing, grid

Имеется следующий код:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private static JLabel portText = new JLabel("Port:");

    public static String getPortValue() {
        return port.getText();
    }

    public static String getBrokerAddressValue() {
        return brokerAddress.getText();
    }

    public static String getTopicValue() {
        return topic.getText();
    }

    public static String getMessageValue() {
        return message.getText();
    }

    public static String getUsernameValue() {
        return username.getText();
    }

    private static JLabel brokerAddressText = new JLabel("Broker ip address:");
    private static JLabel topicText = new JLabel("Topic");
    private static JLabel messageText = new JLabel("Message:");
    private static JLabel usernameText = new JLabel("Username:");
    private static JTextField port = new JTextField(4);
    private static JTextField brokerAddress = new JTextField(10);
    private static JTextField topic = new JTextField(10);
    private static JTextField message = new JTextField(20);
    private static JTextField username = new JTextField(10);
    private static JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");
    private static JButton disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
    private static JButton subscribe = new JButton("Subscribe");
    private static JButton unsubscribe = new JButton("Unsubscribe");
    private static JButton publish = new JButton("Publish");

    MyFrame(){
        super("MQTT client");
        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(jPanel);
        jPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints constraints1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints1.weightx = 0;
        constraints1.weighty = 0;
        constraints1.gridx = 0;
        constraints1.gridy = 0;
        constraints1.gridheight = 1;
        constraints1.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints1.insets.right = 10;
        constraints1.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(portText, constraints1);

        GridBagConstraints constraints2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints2.weightx = 0;
        constraints2.weighty = 0;
        constraints2.gridx = 0;
        constraints2.gridy = 1;
        constraints2.gridheight = 1;
        constraints2.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints2.insets.right = 10;
        constraints2.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(port, constraints2);

        GridBagConstraints constraints3 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints3.weightx = 0;
        constraints3.weighty = 0;
        constraints3.gridx = 1;
        constraints3.gridy = 0;
        constraints3.gridheight = 1;
        constraints3.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints3.insets.right = 10;
        constraints3.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(brokerAddressText, constraints3);

        GridBagConstraints constraints4 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints4.weightx = 0;
        constraints4.weighty = 0;
        constraints4.gridx = 1;
        constraints4.gridy = 1;
        constraints4.gridheight = 1;
        constraints4.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints4.insets.right = 10;
        constraints4.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(brokerAddress, constraints4);

        GridBagConstraints constraints5 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints5.weightx = 0;
        constraints5.weighty = 0;
        constraints5.gridx = 2;
        constraints5.gridy = 0;
        constraints5.gridheight = 1;
        constraints5.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints5.insets.right = 10;
        constraints5.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(connect, constraints5);

        GridBagConstraints constraints6 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints6.weightx = 0;
        constraints6.weighty = 0;
        constraints6.gridx = 2;
        constraints6.gridy = 1;
        constraints6.gridheight = 1;
        constraints6.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints6.insets.right = 10;
        constraints6.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(disconnect, constraints6);

        GridBagConstraints constraints7 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints7.weightx = 0;
        constraints7.weighty = 0;
        constraints7.gridx = 0;
        constraints7.gridy = 3;
        constraints7.gridheight = 1;
        constraints7.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints7.insets.right = 10;
        constraints7.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(topicText, constraints7);

        GridBagConstraints constraints8 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints8.weightx = 0;
        constraints8.weighty = 0;
        constraints8.gridx = 0;
        constraints8.gridy = 4;
        constraints8.gridheight = 1;
        constraints8.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints8.insets.right = 10;
        constraints8.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(topic, constraints8);

        GridBagConstraints constraints9 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints9.weightx = 0;
        constraints9.weighty = 0;
        constraints9.gridx = 1;
        constraints9.gridy = 3;
        constraints9.gridheight = 1;
        constraints9.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints9.insets.right = 10;
        constraints9.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(subscribe, constraints9);

        GridBagConstraints constraints10 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints10.weightx = 0;
        constraints10.weighty = 0;
        constraints10.gridx = 1;
        constraints10.gridy = 4;
        constraints10.gridheight = 1;
        constraints10.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints10.insets.right = 10;
        constraints10.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(unsubscribe, constraints10);

        GridBagConstraints constraints11 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints11.weightx = 0;
        constraints11.weighty = 0;
        constraints11.gridx = 0;
        constraints11.gridy = 6;
        constraints11.gridheight = 1;
        constraints11.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints11.insets.right = 10;
        constraints11.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(messageText, constraints11);

        GridBagConstraints constraints12 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints12.weightx = 0;
        constraints12.weighty = 0;
        constraints12.gridx = 0;
        constraints12.gridy = 7;
        constraints12.gridheight = 1;
        constraints12.gridwidth = 2;
        constraints12.insets.right = 10;
        constraints12.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(message, constraints12);

        GridBagConstraints constraints13 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints13.weightx = 0;
        constraints13.weighty = 0;
        constraints13.gridx = 1;
        constraints13.gridy = 6;
        constraints13.gridheight = 1;
        constraints13.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints13.insets.right = 10;
        constraints13.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(publish, constraints13);

        GridBagConstraints constraints14 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints14.weightx = 0;
        constraints14.weighty = 0;
        constraints14.gridx = 2;
        constraints14.gridy = 3;
        constraints14.gridheight = 1;
        constraints14.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints14.insets.right = 10;
        constraints14.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(usernameText, constraints14);

        GridBagConstraints constraints15 = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints15.weightx = 0;
        constraints15.weighty = 0;
        constraints15.gridx = 2;
        constraints15.gridy = 4;
        constraints15.gridheight = 1;
        constraints15.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints15.insets.right = 10;
        constraints15.insets.bottom = 10;
        jPanel.add(username, constraints15);

        jPanel.revalidate();
        setBounds(750,250,500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

И вроде как некоторые элементы находятся через строку друг от друга, например

```
constraintsN.gridx = 2;
constraintsN.gridx = 0;
```

Но расстояние между ними такое же, как и между двумя соседними рядами. Скорее всего, как я думаю, это из-за того, что ряды между ними (в данном случае 1) не заполнены ничем, поэтому имеют высоту 0. Но как это исправить, ну или как-то по другому задать отступы. Или только отступ снизу от элемента? И еще вопрос, как растянуть например кнопку по ширине всей клетки?

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут подробно расписано
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

А это пример с комментариями:

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import static java.awt.GridBagConstraints.*;

class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private static JLabel portText = new JLabel("Port:");

    public static String getPortValue() {
        return port.getText();
    }

    public static String getBrokerAddressValue() {
        return brokerAddress.getText();
    }

    public static String getTopicValue() {
        return topic.getText();
    }

    public static String getMessageValue() {
        return message.getText();
    }

    public static String getUsernameValue() {
        return username.getText();
    }

    private static JLabel brokerAddressText = new JLabel("Broker ip address:");
    private static JLabel topicText = new JLabel("Topic");
    private static JLabel messageText = new JLabel("Message:");
    private static JLabel usernameText = new JLabel("Username:");
    private static JTextField port = new JTextField(4);
    private static JTextField brokerAddress = new JTextField(10);
    private static JTextField topic = new JTextField(10);
    private static JTextField message = new JTextField(20);
    private static JTextField username = new JTextField(10);
    private static JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");
    private static JButton disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
    private static JButton subscribe = new JButton("Subscribe");
    private static JButton unsubscribe = new JButton("Unsubscribe");
    private static JButton publish = new JButton("Publish");
    private static JButton publish1 = new JButton("Publish");
    private static JButton publish2 = new JButton("Publish");

    private static GridBagConstraints costs(int location, int fill) {
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.weighty = 1.0;
        constraints.weightx = 1.0;
        constraints.fill = fill;
        constraints.anchor = location;
        return constraints;
    }


    private static GridBagConstraints costs(int location, int fill,
                                            int gx, int gy) {
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.weighty = 1.0;
        constraints.weightx = 1.0;
        constraints.gridx = gx;
        constraints.gridy = gy;
        constraints.fill = fill;
        constraints.anchor = location;
        return constraints;
    }

    private static GridBagConstraints costs(int location, int fill,
                                            int gx, int gy,
                                            int gw, int gh) {
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.weighty = 1.0;
        constraints.weightx = 1.0;
        constraints.gridx = gx;
        constraints.gridy = gy;
        constraints.gridwidth = gw;
        constraints.gridheight = gh;
        constraints.fill = fill;
        constraints.anchor = location;
        return constraints;
    }


    private static GridBagConstraints costs(int location, int fill,
                                            int gx, int gy,
                                            int gw, int gh,
                                            int top, int left, int bottom, int right) {
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.weighty = 1.0;
        constraints.weightx = 1.0;
        constraints.gridx = gx;
        constraints.gridy = gy;
        constraints.gridwidth = gw;
        constraints.gridheight = gh;
        constraints.fill = fill;
        constraints.anchor = location;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(top, left, bottom, right);

        return constraints;
    }

    MyFrame() {
        super("MQTT client");


        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        add(jPanel);


        jPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


        //constraints.anchor: положение (внутри ячейки) элемента относительно сторон (вверх,право,центр,углы и тд)
        //сonstraints.fill: заполнение (внутри ячейки) элемента (растягивание)
        //constraints.gridx: положение элемента по x (номер ячейки)
        //constraints.gridy: положение элемента по y (номер ячейки)
        //constraints.gridwidth: длина элемента по x (количество ячеек)
        //constraints.gridheight: ширина элемента по y (количество ячеек)
        //
        //
        //constraints.insets: поля в пикселях вокруг элемента


        //у метода costs есть перегрузка поэтому вводить не обязательно всё
        // (это сильно экономит место и улучшает читабельность кода)
        JTabbedPane jTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        jPanel.add(jTabbedPane,
                //constraints.anchor, сonstraints.fill,
                costs(LAST_LINE_END, BOTH,
                        //constraints.gridx, constraints.gridy
                        0, 0,
                        //constraints.gridwidth, constraints.gridheight
                        0, 0,
                        //constraints.insets
                        //top,left,bottom,right
                        10, 10, 10, 10));


        JPanel page1 = new JPanel();
        page1.setName("PAGE 1");
        JPanel page2 = new JPanel();
        page2.setName("PAGE 2");
        JPanel page3 = new JPanel();
        page3.setName("PAGE 3");


        jTabbedPane.add(page1);
        jTabbedPane.add(page2);
        jTabbedPane.add(page3);


        page1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        page2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        page3.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


        page1.add(portText, costs(PAGE_START, NONE, 0, 0));
        page1.add(port, costs(PAGE_START, HORIZONTAL, 1, 0, 2, 1));
        page1.add(brokerAddressText, costs(PAGE_START, NONE, 0, 1));
        page1.add(brokerAddress, costs(PAGE_START, HORIZONTAL, 1, 1, 2, 1));
        page1.add(connect, costs(LAST_LINE_START, NONE, 0, 2));
        page1.add(publish, costs(PAGE_END, NONE, 1, 2));
        page1.add(disconnect, costs(LAST_LINE_END, NONE, 2, 2));


        page2.add(topicText, costs(LINE_START, NONE, 0, 0));
        page2.add(topic, costs(CENTER, BOTH, 1, 0, 2, 1));
        page2.add(subscribe, costs(LAST_LINE_START, NONE, 0, 2));
        page2.add(publish1, costs(PAGE_END, NONE, 1, 2));
        page2.add(unsubscribe, costs(LAST_LINE_END, NONE, 2, 2));


        page3.add(messageText, costs(LINE_START, NONE, 0, 0));
        page3.add(message, costs(CENTER, BOTH, 1, 0, 2, 1));
        page3.add(publish2, costs(PAGE_END, NONE, 1, 2));


        //set design style, depends on OS:
        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(jPanel);

        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }


        jPanel.revalidate();
        setBounds(750, 250, 500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}
```